# The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, exception

This is an ASP.NET MVC 3 exception message. What it says? What should I do?

OK, I have this code:

```
@{
     Layout = "~/_Layout.cshtml";
     Page.Title = "Home";            
}

@section meta{
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
}

<h2>Html Content Here</h2>

@section footer {
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
    });    
    </script> 
}
```

Comment: Give us source that we can point at and show you your mistake. Don't expect us to do more work than you are.

Comment: @Steve, when you see `Attempted to divide by zero.`, you don't need any source code to tell where the problem is, or explain what is says. I expect a similar explanation. Can't you do that?

Comment: When you see `Attempted to divide by zero` I'd look at the source and point out the zero. Your question does not give enough context to help you. If you don't provide more information, it will be closed.

Comment: I don't know why people vote down, when they can't help.

Comment: Put your mouse over the "vote down" icon and read the tooltip. Then you'll understand. Now that you've updated your question, I'll gladly undo my down-vote.

Comment: `The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page` doesn't seem like it's the whole error message. What's the rest? Specifically the part that lists the sections?

Comment: Check your path to the layout - I was having an issue with Layout sections in an Area. Also name layouts in different areas differently to avoid linking to the wrong one...

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Your layout page isn't actually rendering the sections `footer` and `meta`

In your _Layout.cshtml, put in `@RenderSection("meta")` where you want the meta section rendered.

You can also do `@RenderSection("meta", false)` to indicate that the section is optional.

Answer (score 13):

The error message implies that your `_Layout.cshtml` does not include `@RenderSection` statements for the `@section`s that you have in your view.

Check your Layout and let us know.

See [this page](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 10):

I faced a similar problem where the layout template indeed has the `@RenderSection(...)` but inside an `if-else statement`. So when the page executes the statement that doesn't contain the `@RenderSection` it will throw that exception. If that is your case, then your solution is a little more complicated, either:

- make sure you have `@RenderSection` outside of the statements or
- repeat `@RenderSection` in both if-else statements, or
- use different partial views, or
- redesign the layout.

That could be your main problem!

Comment: I my opinion this is a .net bug - a very anoying one... thx, mentioning this solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

When I received this error I was trying to conditionally include a section in my layout when it was defined by the view. Here is the layout:

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("header"))
{
    RenderSection("header");
}
else
{
    Html.RenderPartial("_Header");
}
```

I think @Jaider mentions this in his answer too, but you cannot place a `RenderSection` inside an if statement. The way to achieve my goal was to inverse the if and set the `required` parameter to false on the `RenderSection` method:

```
@RenderSection("header", false);
@if (!IsSectionDefined("header"))
{
    Html.RenderPartial("_Header");
}
```

If no setion is defined, the first line wont do anything and the If statement ensures a default header is rendered when no section is defined.

Answer (score -2):

usually this error occurs if you do not write code for the section which is required by your master layout-page

Reference: https://ziaahmedshaikh.wordpress.com/2016/02/17/the-following-sections-have-been-defined-but-have-not-been-rendered-for-the-layout-page/